# Django 2.1 - linking user to related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.1

I am creating a Django project, and I want to create profiles of two different user types as a separate model. They will have a OneToOneField relationship with the logged-in user.

```
class UserMusician(models.Model):
    ...

class UserFan(models.Model):
    ...
```

I have seen two different ways of doing this. One, per the Django 2.1 docs shows passing in the `User` model, i.e.:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserMusician(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Whereas other examples, such as the *Two Scoops of Django* book, suggest passing  `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, i.e.:

```
from django.conf import settings

class UserMusician(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH.USER.MODEL)
```

Can anyone tell me what the differences are and what are the advantages and disadvantages to either?

I would like to for these profiles to be generated in the database when a user account is created, one or the other.

(As a 'nice to have', I'd like to allow a UserFan at a later point to become a UserMusician if they decide to switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tje effect is the same, no matter if you use `User` or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to specify the related model. Using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` makes your app more "pluggable" so that it can also be used in projects that use a different user model. So if you want to reuse or release your application to the public `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is for sure the best definition you can use.

If you want to automatically create a profile upon creation of a `User` instance you can use [Django's `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) for doing that:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from models import UserMusician
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        UserMusician.objects.create(user=user)

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Two followup questions: Do I want to put the `post_save` block of code also in the profiles/models.py file with the classes, or somewhere else? If I create both `def create_musician_profile` and also `def create_fan_profile`, how do I keep the from both being created when a new user account is created?

Comment: You can put the code anywhere you like to, as long as you make sure that the `post_save.connect()` gets executed at least once, so `models.py` is fine. You can connect as many functions as you wish to a signal, don't know exactly how you want to decide what kind of profile to create (of course you can also handle both inside one signal handler)